# Timing the runtime of a program via the Terminal

Tags: c++, terminal

I've written a C++ program of which i would like to time the length of time it takes to complete - is there some terminal command i could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "time" command available in most (maybe all) the linux distributions. It will print the time spent as system, as user, and the total time.

For example

```
bash-4.1$ time (sleep 1; sleep 1)
```

will output something like

```
real    0m2.020s
user    0m0.014s
sys 0m0.005s
```

As you can see with the parenthesis you can launch every command chain you wish.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [`time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29) in *nix

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the function several times (1000's probably) so you can get a large enough number.  Then use time.h to create two variables of type time_t - one before execution, one after.  Subtract the two and divide by the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Or [Measure-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347702.aspx) in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I try to better explain :)

If you have compiled your code using g++, for example:

```
g++ -std=c++14 c++/dijkstra_shortest_reach_2.cpp -o dsq
```

In order to run it, you type:

```
./dsq
```

In order to run it with a file content as an input, you type:

```
./dsq < input07Dijkstra.txt
```

Now for the answer.

In order to get the duration of the program output to the screen, just type:

```
time(./dsq < input07Dijkstra.txt)
```

Or without an input:

```
time(./dsq)
```

For the first command my output is:

```
real    0m16.082s
user    0m15.968s
sys     0m0.089s
```

Hope it helps!